# Firebase analytics is not updating screen name after recent update from my Flutter App

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

My app is developed in flutter and running in IOS and Android for past one year. After recent update in 2022 March 1st week I am not getting updated new user count or the screen name of the pages visited by user only from Android.  I am using Mac M1. If I use iphone simulator the screen name appears in analytics (i have suffixed 'ios' and current time to screen name to verify this). But if I use Android simulator page views are not getting updated (probably everything showing under 'not set' or 'others'.

I have added this code in Android manifest.xml as some suggested. but still not working.

This is the code in my initial page.

```
 FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics) ;
    String _message = '';
    void setMessage(String message) {
      // setState(() {
      _message = message;
      myMessage = message;
      // });
    }
    Future<void> _testSetCurrentScreen() async {
      await analytics.setCurrentScreen(
        screenName: myScreenName,
        screenClassOverride: 'AnalyticsDemo',
      );
      setMessage('setCurrentScreen succeeded');
      myMessage = "loaded $myScreenName" ;
    }
    _testSetCurrentScreen();
       print("1476 $myMessage '_' $myMessage");
```